# Issue Navigation - Substring using regex

Tags: regex, intellij-idea

Intellij IDEA 12

I wanted to add a new issue navigation link (Settings -> Version Control -> Issue Navigation) for Bitbucket issues (has pattern: https://bitbucket.org/user/repo-name/issue/123).

I want issue ID would be #n (for instance #3, #123 etc).

How can I input issue ID as a regular expression? **#\d+** ?

Is it possible to make substring using regex expression because it shouldn't be a hash in the Bitbuckt issue URL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following:

```
#(\d+)   --   https://bitbucket.org/user/repo-name/issue/$1
```